# Is there a way to change the NSToolbar background color in fullscreen?

Tags: swift, appkit

I have an `NSWindow` with `titlebarAppearsTransparent` set to `true` which allows me to draw a background color behind the toolbar but in the fullscreen mode the toolbar seems to be ignoring the transparent appearance and has the default window background color, so, is there a way to change the background color of the toolbar in fullscreen?

More info:

- It's a SwiftUI app with a custom/subclass AppDelegate to handle the window appearance.
- I'm only looking for a solution to macOS 11+

Comment: you are mixing titlebarAppearsTransparent vs toolbar. Check if you use correct windowStyleMask

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you found a solution?